# Mutually disjoint triangles in planar cubic graph

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Let $G$ be a connected, planar graph for which every vertex has degree $3$ . Moreover, suppose there is a face of length at least $12$ .

Is it possible to construct an example of such $G $ whose only odd faces are six triangles, and for which no two such triangles share a common vertex?

(For my purposes I may assume there are no faces of length $1$ or $2$, in which case there must be an odd face of length at least 3. By the handshake lemma, there are an even number of, hence at least 2, such odd faces.)

Comment: Triangular prism?

Comment: Thanks again. I've added that only 6 triangles are allowed.

Comment: Why have you repeated your question? The solution given in the first can be easily adapted to this.

Comment: I've added some further restrictions, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest answer: triangular prism.

Niftier solution: the chamfer of any cubic polyhedral having only triangular odd faces. ([Chamfering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chamfer_(geometry)) is a process where you replace each edge with a hexagon.)

Edit, if precisely 6 triangles are allowed, you want a chamfered [cuboctohedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuboctahedron), or any further chamfering.

Edit 2: Start with a 12-gon, C. For 6 disjoint edges in C, create a triangle with a new vertex. Then, pair up triangles and create edges between their newest vertices.

Comment: Sorry to edit, but there must (for my purposes) be even faces length at least 12.

Comment: Might I ask what this is for?

Comment: Solved the new version.

Comment: I have a planar tree with vertices of degree 3 except for one with degree 2. There is an odd, outer face of length at least 5, containing the degree 2 vertex. The inside faces consist of 3 mutually disjoint triangles,disjoint from the outer face, and the rest even. By reflecting this picture at the degree 2 vertex I wrote the above hypothesis. If you think this setup is actually impossible, I will repost a new question of you to answer.